# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem not found

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to use the Hadoop HDFS Java API to list all files in HDFS.
**I am able to list the files on remote HDFS by running the code in my local eclipse.**

But i get the exception

```java
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2290)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2303)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:87)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2342)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2324)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:351)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:163)
```

**when I execute the code from a web server.**

I have added the below maven dependencies.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cdh4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cdh4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cdh4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also I have embedded the required jars into the exported jar and maven has added the same in the buildpath.

If any one has encountered this issue earlier request you to please share the solution.

Comment: have you checked this out? https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!msg/cdh-user/fmLW2NBtOdY/BhU62a_xucYJ
perhaps it's because your webserver doesn't read some env. variables in `.basrc` or `.profiles` like your local eclipse does..

Comment: The web server **is not on the server** where hadoop is installed.
I am trying to execute hdfs commands on remote Hadoop HDFS  using Java API.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar issue with Apache hadoop 2.2.0 realease, I did a workaround by running it as a separate process, by

```
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("java -jar {jarfile} {classfile}";
final Scanner output = new Scanner (p.getErrorStream ());
while (output.hasNext ()) {
            try {
                System.err.println (output.nextLine ());
            } catch (final Exception e) {

            }
 }
```

The jar file contains the implementation using the apache hadoop 2.2.0 jars.

Though, I am still searching for an exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me, hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0.jar was missing in zeppelin server's lib dir. I copied in zeppelin lib forder and my problem was resolved. :)
and add dependency for hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0.jar in pom.xml also.